# How do I extract a multi-level compressed file (recursion) with 7-zip in one command?

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

If possible, how can a file that's been compressed in multiple levels, like the following example.7z file, be extracted in a single ***command***? Assume there is only one final uncompressed file.

```
example.7z
    └ database.sql.gz
          └ database.sql
```

One way to extract this in a single ***line***, is to use the following:

```
7z e /path/to/example.7z database.sql.gz && 7z e database.sql.gz
```

However, this chains two commands and requires that I know the filename of each level.

I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this with a single ***command***.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You didn't explain how your 7zipper would know what files to pick regardless of one command or not as in `know the filename of each level`.  You don't say where they would come from.  I totally understand if this is for personal edification but I myself could probably pull off what you are asking but wouldn't even try.  A quick bash function and not only do I have several commands and logic accessible via a single command, I have something someone else can understand.  Good luck though!  Perhaps a genius here is bored enough to take this on.

Comment: I recommend you do not. The SQL script could be humongous. It’s better to leave it compressed to the last moment, if possible.

Comment: 7z doesn't have any options for this. You can make a one-liner for thsi specific use-case with a pipe or &&, but you still need to know the filename of the file inside the 7z file. So you may need a "7z l" to list the content of the outer file anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're referring to a pipeline, like this example from `man 7z`

```
-so    Write data to stdout
       (e.g. 7z x -so directory.tar.7z | tar xf -)
```

You still need to know what command to pipe into, but it saves writing any temporary files. For your example I think piping into `gunzip` and then writing to a file should work:

```
7z e -so example.7z database.sql.gz | gunzip > database.sql
```

---

- FYI You can do some elaborate operations with pipelines, especially when adding `tee` and process substitution, take a look at `info tee` for examples.
- Another option is using a different archive format, instead of 7z or tar.gz/tar.xz...

  - `squashfs` files can be mounted and read just like any regular filesystem, only they're read-only and compressed. Excellent for browsing & reading one or two files out of a huge archive. It's what almost every live Linux ISO uses to compress their main filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

To extract a multi-level compressed file with 7-Zip using a single command, you can use the following syntax:

```
7z x -r archive.7z -odestination_folder
```

Here's a breakdown of the command:

- `7z`: The command to execute 7-Zip.
- `x`: Stands for eXtract with full paths.
- `-r`: Recursively process subdirectories.
- `archive.7z`: The name of your compressed file.
- `-odestination_folder`: Specifies the destination folder where the contents should be extracted. Replace "destination_folder" with the actual path where you want the files to be extracted.

For example, if your compressed file is named "example.7z" and you want to extract it to a folder called "extracted", the command would be:

```
7z x -r example.7z -oextracted
```

Make sure to replace "example.7z" with the actual name of your compressed file and "extracted" with the desired destination folder.

Comment: This is WRONG. The -r switch is ONLY for compressing. It tells 7z to look for the files(s) to compress in sub-folders. Usually used in combination with wildcards e.g.: 7z a all_txt_files.7z -r *.txt , which would add all TXT files in thsi folder and sub-folders to all_txt_files.7z